# python threading.Timer start immediately not at specified time

Tags: python, multithreading

i want to execute a function in every 3 second
the code works if i call a function without arguments like below:

```
def mytempfunc():
    print "this is timer!"
    threading.Timer(5, mytempfunc).start()
```

but if i call a function with argument like this:

```
def myotherfunc(a,b,c,d):
    print "this is timer!"
    threading.Timer(5, myotherfunc(a,b,c,d)).start()
```

the new thread will be created and started immediately without waiting for 5 seconds.
is there anything that i missed?

Comment: The tabs on this aren't right and your second example is calling mytempfunc, which doesn't seem right.  Could you edit your question?

Comment: Tabs still look off...

Comment: note: `Timer()` executes the function only once. See [related question you want to call function repeatedly every n seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12435211/4279)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
threading.Timer(5, myotherfunc, [a,b,c,d]).start()
```

In your code, you actually call myotherfunc(a,b,c,d), rather than passing your function and arguments to the [Timer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) class.

Comment: Excellent catch. I am new to python and couldn't figure out why the code was behaving the way it was.