# run a "linux" sleep in background from python

Tags: python, linux, bash, execute

I have a python script, which should execute a shell script. But it should sleep 30 seconds before executing. I want the script to sleep in the background and then execute it.

The Shell Command should be like this:
If I type this command directly to the console, it works.

```
(sleep 30 && /root/bin/myscript.sh parameter1 parameter2) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Now from python: (I have divided the commands)

```
subprocess.call(['/bin/sleep', '30', '&'])
subprocess.call(['/root/bin/myscript.sh', str(dom), str(limit), '&'])
```

(str(dom) and str(limit) are the 2 parameters)

I get this error:

```
/bin/sleep: invalid time interval `&'
```

Why does it take `&` as parameter instead of 30?

Comment: Why don't you just use `time.sleep(secs)`? http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep

Comment: I want to go back to the console and dont wait 20 second until the script is executed.

Comment: Calling `sleep` in the background will simply cause `myscript.sh` to run in parallel with, not after, the `sleep`. Multiple calls to  `subprocess.call` do not queue the processes they start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because `&` is being passed to the `/bin/sleep` command as an argument, whereas you are using it in the context of telling the shell to execute the command in the background.

If you want to use '&' or '&&' you can use `os.system`:

`os.system('sleep 1 && echo foo && sleep 5 && echo bar')`

or to run nonblocking (in the background) you can use the standard `&`:

`os.system('sleep 1 && echo foo && sleep 5 && echo bar &')`

Comment: Yes, that works :) Now, I only need to implement the parameters str(dom) and str(limit). Like `os.system('sleep 20 && /root/bin/myscript.sh str(dom) str(limit) &')` Of course not as string :D

Comment: Be careful if you are using untrusted, user-provided strings (e.g. from a webserver), as otherwise you may vulnerable to shell injection.

Comment: It's an internal server. And the python script is from xen ;)
I tried it with `os.system('/bin/sleep 20 && /root/bin/myscript.sh %s %s &' % (str(dom), str(limit)))` Error: `sh: Syntax error: "&" unexpected`

Comment: That's odd, `&`ing a os.system command works for me. What environment is this?

Comment: Debian 6.0.4 with Xen. Python 2.7.2+ is running.
But with your sample command, it works. :S

Comment: It works now. I had to strip the both variables. Perhaps, there was a tabulator or whitespace :/ Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you are wanting to do, force a python script to run in the background every time. Python also can't run a task directly in the background. You might look into [Threading](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html), which might accomplish what you want, but without knowing why you want to go back to the command prompt, it's difficult. I think what you might want is a threading timer specifically, an example of which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3433565/544198).

```
from threading import Timer

def hello():
    print "hello, world"

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start() # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```

Comment: I dont want to run the python script in the background. Only the 2 shell commands :)

Answer (score 1):

Call with one string:

```
prc = subprocess.Popen('/bin/sleep 3; echo Some string', shell=True)
```

Note, I remove `&`.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` run in backgroung and not block main Pythjon process. See update.

Comment: Yes, you fixed it :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
subprocess.Popen(["sh","-c","sleep 30; /root/bin/myscript.sh parameter1 parameter2"])
```

You can build the command line for parameter1, parameter2 using string concatenation.

But as described in PearsonArtPhoto's answer, using thread is better option.