# Discord.py auto send a message after a specific time since last message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have searched all internet but i cant seem to find a way to send a message after a specific amount of time since the last message in a channel, if its possible to make this, is it also possible to make a selfbot that can do this? I want to make a selfbot for my alt because i want to learn those things too and stuff y know. (Its in discord.py btw.)

Comment: Can you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433559/python-time-delays and try to implement for your problem, I'm not sure if discord.py allows this but should work. Whenever you get message use the timer that's mentioned in the link above. and inside of that use message send function.

Comment: @ExDet Alr Ill check it out

Comment: Discord.py does not support selfbots.

Comment: really? Thats sad.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community so I'm trying to make a bot/self bot that automatically sends a message after 2 minutes since the last message

Answer (score 1):

Technically, from experience you can still somewhat make selfbots with discord.py. Not sure if they removed the ability to, but if you log into the bot via your token instead of the bots token it should work fine. Then just check 'on_message', and if the message is sent by you and the contents are whats needed, you can use something like this:

```
import asyncio

async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id = 'YOUR ID':
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await message.channel.send('Delayed by 5 seconds.')
```