# Auto decrementing attribute of instance of a class inside a class method in python

Tags: python, oop, concurrency

```python
class Patient:
    list_all = []

    def __init__(self, initial_oxygen_sat):
        self.initial_oxygen_sat = initial_oxygen_sat
        self.current_oxygen_sat = self.initial_oxygen_sat
        self.timebetweenupdates = random.randint(1, 6)

        Patient.list_all.append(self)

        self.updateOxygen()

    def updateOxygen(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(self.timebetweenupdates)
            self.current_oxygen_sat -= 1
```

Basically, I have a `Patient` class and each instance has an initial oxygen level.

What I'm trying to do is, each time an instance of `Patient` is created, its oxygen level should start dropping by one after every `timebetweenupdates` seconds, which is randomly decided for each instance.

```
p1 = Patient(100)
print(p1.current_oxygen_sat)
```

I tried running this code, and the print statement never executed. Maybe the while loop cannot run in the background indefinitely like this? I would appreciate any help to understand why this doesn't work like this, and also how to actually implement this.

PS: I've been introduced to OOP just a few days ago so bear with me please :)

Comment: The `time.sleep` call blocks the thread so nothing else happens until the sleep finishes, then it continues to the next line... and the infinite loop in the method called from `__init__` prevents any subsequent code from being reached.

Comment: There are probably a few ways to do this, here's one https://stackoverflow.com/a/3433565/202168

Comment: `while True:` will run until you specify a `break` or an exception happens.

Comment: @Daviid yes that was the intention, but I wanted it to "run in the background" if that makes sense.

Comment: @Anentropic Thanks a lot! `threading` was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Using @Anentropic answer you could use 'self.t = threading.Timer(self.timebetweenupdates, self.updateOxygen)' then `self.t.start()` in the init function, and inside the `updateOxygen` you check if it's time to stop the timer and `self.t.cancel()`

Comment: `self.t = threading.Timer(self.timebetweenupdates, self.updateOxygen())` doesn't seem to work, it says None type argument cannot be passed as argument function (`updateOxygen()`)

Comment: you have to pass the function itself as an argument, not the result of calling the function (i.e. `Timer` will call the function for you after the elapsed time)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand: `updateOxygen()` is the function and I passed it as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, code in Python or any other popular language is single-threaded, non concurrent: that means that once you call the function that features that  `while True:` block, it will never end, and any line after that will never be executed *at all*.

Fortunately, over the years, more and more concurrency models are put on the table for us to pick and use - but any of them will require an explicit setup.

Keep in mind that "one code" will always be the "root" code that is running and making calls for the rest of code you want to run concurrently. Usually programs will run user-written code until at some point control is passed to a controlling loop, which will from that point on orchestrate the calls and time-sharing.
(This is one model for running concurrent code, not the only one - but one that is easy to maintain).

In Python, with no GUI libraries, a close - and popular - model to run what you intend is asychronous code , by using the "asyncio" library. In it, the loop is created by a call to specific methods in the `asyncio` lib, which can  in turn call functions or methods created as `async def`, and featuring `await` expressions in its body.  There is a special version of `sleep` to go with it, that instead of blocking your program, tells the asyncio loop it can run other tasks until it is time to come back for the next line after the `await` expression.

That said, a small re-write to some of your code will turn it into proper asyncio. Other approaches would include using explicit multi-threading (but that would take a lot of resources per Patient instance, compared to asyncio code), or using callbacks and scheduling calls after some time, using the main loop in a GUI oriented library, like tkinter or Pyqt.

```
import asyncio

class Patient:
    list_all = []

    def __init__(self, initial_oxygen_sat):
        self.initial_oxygen_sat = initial_oxygen_sat
        self.current_oxygen_sat = self.initial_oxygen_sat
        self.timebetweenupdates = random.randint(1, 6)

        Patient.list_all.append(self)

        self.updateOxygen()

    async def updateOxygen(self):
        while True:
            await asycio.sleep(self.timebetweenupdates)
            self.current_oxygen_sat -= 1
            
            if self.current_oxygen_sat <= 0:
                # this guy is a gonner!
                self.dead = True
                return


asynd def entry_point():
    tasks = set()
    p1 = Patient(100)
    tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(p1.updateOxyegen()))
    
    # you can instantiate more patients and create their updating tasks here
    ...
    
    # this will wait until all tasks exit:
    while tasks:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=1)
        print(p1.current_oxygen_sat)
        tasks = pending
      
asyncio.run(entry_point())
```